# Drawing tree not visible; maybe layout issue

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, draw

I want to display a tree.
But the tree does not appear.
What is the problem?

Main:

```
package scanner_parser;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Oberflaeche gui = new Oberflaeche();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

GUI:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Oberflaeche extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel cp, top, bottom;
    private JTextField eingabefeld = new JTextField();
    private JButton button = new JButton("Darstellen");
    private JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem anleitung, beenden, bEins, bZwei, bDrei, bVier;
    private Baum baum = new Baum();

    public Oberflaeche() {
        this.setTitle("Funktionsparser");
        this.setSize(900, 700);
        this.setLocation(300, 100);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initMenu();

        cp = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 1));
        top = new JPanel();
        top.setLayout(null);
        top.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), 50);
        top.setBackground(Color.white);

        bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setBounds(0, 50, getWidth(), getHeight() - 50);
        bottom.setBackground(Color.white);

        eingabefeld.setBounds(10, 10, getWidth() - 120, 30);
        button.setBounds(getWidth() - 110, 10, 100, 30);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        top.add(button);
        top.add(eingabefeld);
        cp.add(top);
        cp.add(bottom);
    }

    // Initialise Menu

    private void initMenu() {
        menu = new JMenu("Datei");
        anleitung = new JMenuItem("Anleitung");
        anleitung.addActionListener(this);

        menu.add(anleitung);
        beenden = new JMenuItem("Beenden");
        beenden.addActionListener(this);

        menu.add(beenden);
        menubar.add(menu);

        menu = new JMenu("Beispiele");

       // Load some example functions into the textfield

        bEins = new JMenuItem("<html>3 * x</html>");
        bEins.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(bEins);

        bZwei = new JMenuItem("<html>3 * x<sup>2</sup></html>");
        bZwei.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(bZwei);

        bDrei = new JMenuItem("<html>3 * ( x<sup>2</sup> + 1 )</html>");
        bDrei.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(bDrei);

        bVier = new JMenuItem("<html>3 * ( x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>4</sup> + 1 )</html>");
        bVier.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(bVier);

        menubar.add(menu);

        this.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object s = e.getSource();

        if (s == anleitung) {

        }

       // This should add the tree (baum) but it does not appear.


        if (s == button) {
            FuncParser.theParser().parse(eingabefeld.getText());
            FuncParser.theParser().getWurzel().print();
            bottom.add(baum);
        }
        if (s == beenden) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (s == bEins) {
            eingabefeld.setText("3*x");
        }
        if (s == bZwei) {
            eingabefeld.setText("3*x^2");
        }
        if (s == bDrei) {
            eingabefeld.setText("3*(x^2+1)");
        }
        if (s == bVier) {
            eingabefeld.setText("3*(x^2+x^4+1)");
        }
    }
}
```

The Tree class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Baum extends JPanel {

    private final int radius = 20;
    private final int paddingY = 75;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("test");
        displayBaum(g, FuncParser.theParser().getWurzel(), getWidth() / 2, 100, 20 + getWidth() / 4);
    }

    private void displayBaum(Graphics g, Knoten k, int x, int y, int paddingX) {
        g.drawOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        g.drawString(k.getDaten(), x - 4, y + 4);

        if (k.getLinks() != null) {
            displayKante(g, x - paddingX, y + paddingY, x, y);
            displayBaum(g, k.getLinks(), x - paddingX, y + paddingY, 10 + paddingX / 2);
            displayKante(g, x + paddingX, y + paddingY, x, y);
            displayBaum(g, k.getLinks(), x + paddingX, y + paddingY, 10 + paddingX / 2);
        }
    }

    private void displayKante(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        double d = Math.sqrt(paddingY * paddingY + (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1));
        int x11 = (int) (x1 - radius * (x1 - x2) / d);
        int y11 = (int) (y1 - radius * (y1 - y2) / d);
        int x21 = (int) (x2 + radius * (x1 - x2) / d);
        int y21 = (int) (y2 + radius * (y1 - y2) / d);
        g.drawLine(x11, y11, x21, y21);
    }
}
```

The text "test" appear in the console every time I scale the window.
This means the function is called but the tree does not appear on the content pane. Maybe its underneath something? I don't now why. Please help if you have an idea.

Comment: Please do not vandalize questions. If you've solved your problem, either close your question as not reproducible or write an answer detailing how. You can also delete your answer by clicking the grey "delete" link under the tags.

Comment: Please don't deface your question, if you wish to delete your post click the `delete` button instead.

Answer (score 2):

Reducing your fragments to a compilable state, I get the following results. In particular,

- Don't use a `null` layout; the example uses the default `BorderLayout` for `JFrame` and `FlowLayout` for `Panel`.
- Use the [`JTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField-int-) constructor that lets you specify the field's width in columns.
- Override [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) to establish the drawing area's initial geometry, and draw relative to its current dimensions.
- Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Use `equals()` in preference to `==` in your `ActionListener`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * @See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215252/230513
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Oberflaeche gui = new Oberflaeche();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static class Baum extends JPanel {

        private final int radius = 20;
        private final int paddingY = 75;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawString("Hello", 16, 16);
            displayKante(g, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(329, 240);
        }

        private void displayKante(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            double d = Math.sqrt(paddingY * paddingY + (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1));
            int x11 = (int) (x1 - radius * (x1 - x2) / d);
            int y11 = (int) (y1 - radius * (y1 - y2) / d);
            int x21 = (int) (x2 + radius * (x1 - x2) / d);
            int y21 = (int) (y2 + radius * (y1 - y2) / d);
            g.drawLine(x11, y11, x21, y21);
        }
    }

    private static class Oberflaeche extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        private JPanel top, bottom;
        private JTextField eingabefeld = new JTextField(20);
        private JButton button = new JButton("Darstellen");
        private JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        private JMenu menu;
        private JMenuItem anleitung, beenden, bEins, bZwei, bDrei, bVier;
        private Baum baum = new Baum();

        public Oberflaeche() {
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setTitle("Funktionsparser");
            initMenu();
            top = new JPanel();
            top.setBackground(Color.white);
            top.add(button);
            top.add(eingabefeld);
            button.addActionListener(this);
            bottom = new JPanel();
            bottom.setBackground(Color.white);
            bottom.add(new JLabel("Label text."));
            this.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.add(baum);
            this.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            this.pack();
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }

        // Initialise Menu
        private void initMenu() {
            menu = new JMenu("Datei");
            anleitung = new JMenuItem("Anleitung");
            anleitung.addActionListener(this);
            menu.add(anleitung);
            beenden = new JMenuItem("Beenden");
            beenden.addActionListener(this);
            menu.add(beenden);
            menubar.add(menu);
            menu = new JMenu("Beispiele");
            // Load some example functions into the textfield
            bEins = new JMenuItem("<html>3 * x</html>");
            bEins.addActionListener(this);
            menu.add(bEins);
            bZwei = new JMenuItem("<html>3 * x<sup>2</sup></html>");
            bZwei.addActionListener(this);
            menu.add(bZwei);
            bDrei = new JMenuItem("<html>3 * ( x<sup>2</sup> + 1 )</html>");
            bDrei.addActionListener(this);
            menu.add(bDrei);
            bVier = new JMenuItem("<html>3 * ( x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>4</sup> + 1 )</html>");
            bVier.addActionListener(this);
            menu.add(bVier);
            menubar.add(menu);
            this.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object s = e.getSource();
            if (s == anleitung) {
                System.out.println(anleitung);
            }
            if (s == button) {
                System.out.println(button);
            }
            if (s == beenden) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (s == bEins) {
                eingabefeld.setText("3*x");
            }
            if (s == bZwei) {
                eingabefeld.setText("3*x^2");
            }
            if (s == bDrei) {
                eingabefeld.setText("3*(x^2+1)");
            }
            if (s == bVier) {
                eingabefeld.setText("3*(x^2+x^4+1)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding both panels to the center of the content pane, `cp`, and you never add `baum`. Use constraints on the panels like this:

```
cp.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
cp.add(baum, BorderLayout.CENTER);
cp.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```